# R: different classes of result of seq()

Tags: r, class, seq

Why is the output the following way in R?

```
> class(seq(1,10))
[1] "integer"
> class(seq(1,10,1))
[1] "numeric"
```

Is it because one could call `seq(1,10,0.5)` and thus create double values? But then why dont't I check if the starting point and step size are integer or is this too much effort?

Comment: seq.int and the default method of seq for numeric arguments return a vector of type "integer" or "double": programmers should not rely on which.

Comment: Hm ok I should read the documentation... But is it just definition or is there something more fundamental behind this choice?

Comment: Provide integer inputs for integer outputs, `class(seq(1L, 10L, 1L))`.

Comment: See http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/seq-int-does-not-return-a-sequence-of-integers-sometimes-td4723484.html which also discusses this, and claims 1 gets read as numeric unless you do as @MartinMorgan suggests. Also seq.int, they say, has int for internsl, not integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the third option that you have given. Integer cannot take decimal values in R while numeric can. When you define it without the third argument, it is going to take the class as integer, but when you define the third argument, it can be a floating value too. So R defined it that way